# How to save a dict with dicts as values into a csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below:

```
myDict={ "1": subdict1, "2": subdict2, ...}
```

Each subdict looks like this:

```
subdictn={"feature1":An(string) , "feature2":Bn(integer) , "feature3":Cn(datetime), ...}
```

How can I save it into a dataframe or a csv file to look like this:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9nPi.png)

Comment: What do you mean by `An(string)`?

Comment: `@FatihAkici` , I meant they are of different types, A is a string, B is an integer and ...

Comment: What is `An`? What does that `n` stand for?

Comment: It means it's for subdictn, A1 is fr subdict1, A2 is for subditc2, ...

Comment: I see now. For reproducibility, please specify a value for n and give specific examples wth real values instead of abstract variable names. The vagueness in your question can attract a lot of low quality answer attempts (it already did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. My assumption is that every subdict has the same keys otherwise you would get errors or not write everything.:

```
import csv

x1 = {"f1":"A", "f2":3}
x2 = {"f1":"B", "f2":14}

header = list(x1.keys()) 

myDict={ "1": x1, "2": x2}

with open('file.csv', mode='w', newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(["key"]+header)
    for subkey in myDict:
        writer.writerow([subkey]+[myDict[subkey][k] for k in header])
```

## File content:

```
key,f1,f2
1,A,3
2,B,14
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you:

```
d = {'1': {"feature1":"A1" , "feature2":"B1"}, 
    '2': {"feature1":"A2" , "feature2":"B2"}}
f = open('test.csv', 'w')
for key in d.keys():
    f.write("{}".format(key))
    for k in d[key].keys():
        f.write(",{}".format(d[key][k]))
    f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

Output:

```
1,A1,B1
2,A2,B2
```